# Handling multiple delimiters within multiple quotation marks in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a field within a CSV file that contains a large amount of information which I am trying to keep together. The issue I am having is there is multiple quote marks and commas within this piece of information.

If I add a quotechar = '?' before letting python read the data it works perfectly (minus a couple of extra quote marks but I can work with that), however, I would ultimately like:

1 - Not have to add the quotechar = ? entirely.

2 - Before reading the file Python adds the ? to the start and end of the string before it is read.

Also if I try to provide the problem with the data manually added to a dataframe the error does not show as I am manually ending where the output should end.

```
import pandas as pd

dfDoesNotWork = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(strInputLink + strTradeFile1, header = None, skiprows = 1))

dfWorksButNeedToAddQuoteChar = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(strInputLink + strTradeFile1, header = None, skiprows = 1, quotechar = '?'))
```

The raw input data:

```
0,1,2
Works," ""(""Apple""=""Apple"""," ""Orange""=""Orange"""," ""Pear""=""Pear"""," ""Bananna""="""")""",Works
```

Input data after manually adding ? to start and end of string:

```
0,1,2
Works,?" ""(""Apple""=""Apple"""," ""Orange""=""Orange"""," ""Pear""=""Pear"""," ""Bananna""="""")"""?,Works
```

This is what my problem is:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
0   " ""(""Apple""=""Apple"""   " ""Orange""=""Orange"""    " ""Pear""=""Pear"""    " ""Bananna""="""")"""  Works
```

This is what I can achieve when manually adding ? and using the quotechar = ? in the pd.readcsv. Note the additonal quote marks, I can handle this but would rather not:

```
    0   1   2
0   Works   """ """"(""""Apple""""=""""Apple"""""","" """"Orange""""=""""Orange"""""","" """"Pear""""=""""Pear"""""","" """"Bananna""""="""""""")"""""""    Works



What I ultimately what to achieve:
    0   1   2
0   Works   """(""Apple""=""Apple"",""Orange""=""Orange"",""Pear=""Pear"",""Bananna""="""")"""  Works
```